# How to run imacro on a list of URL

Tags: automation, firefox-addon, imacros

I've recorded a macro to run on a specific url.

How do I run the same macro on multiple list of URLs (around 100 URLs)?

Note: The URLs are stored in a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)Change extension of url file to `.csv` ans save it to the imacro directory:

2) Add this code to your existing code and `Play As Loop`:

```
TAB T=1   
SET !LOOP 1  
SET !DATASOURCE urls.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
```

explanation: open datasource, loop over it's lines and for each line go to the url at Column1 (if you want more info per site like user and pass you can add at the csv file like url,user,pass and use `COL2` and `COL3` for the user and pass info)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your suggested code, but it only takes the first entry in the csv file. It doesnt seem to be looping through all the entries in the csv file.

Comment: did you play your macro in a loop and put a high max value as the "max" field? below the play/pause/stop buttons you have another button to play as loop. If you did play as loop, what error do you get? for debugging you can also try to remove the `SET !LOOP 1`